# How can I use regex case convertion tokens (\u \l \U \L \E) in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, pcre

I want to let the user provide both the pattern and the replace string for the **PHP** preg_replace function.

This code works for me:

`echo preg_replace('/(o)/', ', ${1}h!', 'hello'); // echoes 'hell, oh!'`

Case conversion tokens, i.e. `\u`, `\l`, `\U`, `\L` and `\E`, within the replace string don't work for me though. Here'an example of the code I'm trying to execute:

`echo preg_replace('/(o)/', '\u${1}','hello'); // expected to echo 'hellO', echoes 'hell\uo'`

Because the replacement string is dynamic, I believe I can't implement this case conversion functionality using callback functions instead of a plain replacement string.

These are the things I tried but to no avail:

- Escaping the backslash resulting in this code:

`echo preg_replace('/(o)/u', '\\u${1}','hello');`

- Regex modifier `/u` making the code look like this. I didn't think that would work, but I've read about that somewhere. Trying didn't hurt:

`echo preg_replace('/(o)/u', '\u${1}','hello');`

- Checking if there is any info about this on regex101.com, here you can find the very functionality I'm trying to achieve in my PHP code: https://regex101.com/r/7VXijL/1. Notice how on the left side you can use the Code Generator to create PHP code. Generated code has the very same issue for me as described above though (echoes `The result of the substitution is hell\uo`, even when I executed it on https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com)

The current situation is that I'm confused about where my mistake might be:

1. wrong PCRE version installed
2. using preg_replace in a wrong way
3. using `\u`, `\l`, `\U`, `\L`, `\E` in a wrong way
4. is implementing this functionality even possible using **PHP** (I'm using 7.4.7)?

@1: I got utterly confused if PCRE2 was suddenly renamed to PCRE at some point and I'm therefore already good to go. I couldn't find anything about installing PCRE2 for PHP under **Windows** though. I don't mind using a virtual machine with Linux on it if that's the issue. Here's what `phpinfo();` tells me about my PCRE:

```
pcre
PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support => enabled
PCRE Library Version => 10.34 2019-11-21
PCRE Unicode Version => 12.1.0
PCRE JIT Support => enabled
PCRE JIT Target => x86 64bit (little endian + unaligned)
```

@2&3: Looking forward to hearing about your corrections

@4: I might be able to execute Perl script through PHP then or some command tool that supports this kind of functionality. Would there be any cool options here?

Comment: I don't think `preg_replace()` implements operators in the replacement string. It uses PCRE for matching, but not replacing.

Comment: @Barmar I'm currently looking at this reference here: [https://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplacecase.html](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplacecase.html). If you select `PCRE2` from a dropdown on top of the page it will display some kind of support for functionality I'm looking for. It does say 'extended' however. I don't have an idea what that means though.

Comment: Select PHP from the dropdowns, and notice that the right column is full of "no".

Comment: So PHP 7.4.7 with PCRE v10.34 doesn't support it at all then? My issue is that [https://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplacecase.html](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplacecase.html) doesn't name any particular PHP version while [https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.installation.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.installation.php) says PHP 7.3+ is required to have PCRE2 included.

Comment: I don't see anything about it in the PHP documentation. The only dynamic values in the replacement string are `$n` for the nth capture group.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use function in the replacement, you have to use [preg_replace-callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback). The code generated by regex101 is wrong.

```
$res = preg_replace_callback('/(o)/', 
    function ($m) {
        return strtoupper($m[1]);
    },
    'hello'
);

echo $res;
```

**Output:**

```
hellO
```

Comment: My problem with this solution is that the functionality is hardcoded into the function. I on the other hand want the user to be able to specify what parts of the match he wants to be upper case (`\U...\E`, `\u`) or lower case (`\L...\E`, `\l`). Long story short it seems that I can't implement this using PHP only. Therefore I will create another question concerning my issue and link it here.

Comment: @JennyHoweling: A perl implementation can do the job. Or you can parse the regex and rewrite something that can be used by php.